# Explanation of the dynamic programming subproblem for House robber problem?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I have a question understanding subproblem in dynamic programming. For example:

Problem statement is as follows

```
You are a professional robber planning to rob houses along a street. Each house has a certain amount of money stashed, the only constraint stopping you from robbing each of them is that adjacent houses have security system connected and it will automatically contact the police if two adjacent houses were broken into on the same night.

Given a list of non-negative integers representing the amount of money of each house, determine the maximum amount of money you can rob tonight without alerting the police.
```

Input is

```
nums = [1,2,3,1]
```

The subproblem relation everybody is using is

```
dp[i] = Math.max(nums[i]+dp[i-2], dp[i-1])
```

Can somebody explain to me the logic behind the dynamic programming recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially 3 conditions

1. numHouse == 0, moneySteal = 0
2. numHouse == 1, moneySteal = nums[0] // only one element in the array.

Now the interesting case where robber can steal from the houses not adjacent to each other.

Now here, at i'th house we have already computed

```
dp[i-1]: Max loot till i-1 house
dp[i-2]: Max loot till i-2 house
```

So, the robber has a choice at i'th house.

If robber loots i'th house that means it didn't loot i-1 house as these two are adjacent.

Or the robber can see whether not looting i'th house is beneficial as loot value i-1 house will be more which is denoted by dp[i-1]

So, robber maximizes the loot amount at i'th house by checking which one is more (nums[i] + dp[i-2]) i.e. loot ith house or not loot ith house as dp[i-1] is bigger.

```
  dp[i] = Math.max(nums[i]+dp[i-2], dp[i-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

if given array `nums=[1]` you return 1.

if given array `nums=[1,2]`, you return `max(1,2)`

if given array `nums=[1,2,3]`, since you cannot visit adjacent houses, you either visit the 2nd house and skip the 1st and 3rd house or you skip the 2nd house and visit the 1st and the 3rd house. Now you chose which way returns the maximum money. So you return

```
max((1+3),2)
```

This is the logic. It is simple but since its name is dynamic programming it scares people.

This is just the code translation of above description:

```
dp[i] = Math.max(nums[i]+dp[i-2], dp[i-1])
```